Let $a_1=2/5, a_{n+1}=a_n+a_n^2/n^2$, prove that $a_n<1$
$$
\mbox{Let}\qquad a_{1} = {2 \over 5},\quad a_{n + 1} = a_{n} + \frac{a_{n}^{2}}{n^{2}}
$$
Prove that
$a_{n} < 1,\ \forall\ \mbox{positive integers}\ n$.

I have tried to play around with the sequence and i have tried to compute the telescoping sum $\sum_{n}\left( a_{n + 1} - a_{n}\right) = \sum_{n}a_{n}^{2}/n^{2}$ and tried to use tools like summation by parts, but it doesn't seem to work.
And the conclusion seems to be dependent on the initial value, for example, if we set $a_{1} = 0.45$, then
$a_{n} > 1$ for sufficiently large $n$.
I notice that the sequence is strictly increasing and positive,
but not sure if it helps.

Thanks in advance

I would try induction. The naive induction hypotesis $a_n < 1$ does not work, but something like $a_n < 1 - A/n$ for a suitable $A$ looks like it could.

@Winther Yes, use Mathematical Induction to prove that $a_n \le 1 - 1/n$ for all $n\ge 3$.

Method one: (without $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$)
Note that: $a_1=2/5<1,a_2=14/25<1,a_3=399/625<1,$
$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{n^2+a_n},\quad \forall n\in\mathbb N.$$
So
$$\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_n}
=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{a_k}-\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2+a_k}\\
=\frac{1}{1+a_1}+\frac{1}{4+a_2}+\sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2+a_k}\\
<\frac57+\frac{25}{114}+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)k}
=\frac57+\frac{25}{114}+\frac12,\quad \forall n\geq4.$$
Hence, we can get
$$\frac{1}{a_n}>\frac52-\frac57-\frac{25}{114}-\frac12
=\frac{851}{798}>1,\quad \forall n\geq4.$$
Method two: (with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$)
$a_1=2/5=0.4<1,a_2=14/25=0.56<1,a_3=399/625=0.6384<1,a_4=0.683\cdots<1,$
Suppose when $k=5,\cdots,n$, we have $a_k<1$,
then $$a_{n+1}-a_4=\sum_{k=4}^n(a_{k+1}-a_k)
=\sum_{k=4}^n\frac{a_k^2}{k^2}
<\sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}
=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-\frac14-\frac19.$$
i.e.,$$a_{n+1}<\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-\frac14-\frac19+a_4<1.$$

How do you get the equality
$$
\sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{a_k^2}{k^2}
\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-\frac14-\frac19
$$
??

@
quasi Thank you for your comment. Use
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$ and some typo! (fixed it)

But $a_k^2/k^2$ is not the same as $1/k^2$.

@ quasi $$\sum_{k=4}^n\frac{a_k^2}{k^2}<\sum_{k=4}^n\frac{1}{k^2}
<\sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}.$$

The above inequality assumes $a_k < 1$.

@ quasi By induction, wo suppose $a_k<1,$ when $k=5,6,\cdots,n$.

@Riemann Thank you so much!, is there any reason/ motivation to consider $1/a_n$? It seems very smart but I don't see how or why one would consider that in the first place.

@  Ishigami
Telescoping sequence and $\frac{1}{k^2+a_k}<\frac{1}{(k-1)k}$  is better than $\frac{a^2_k}{k^2}<\frac1{k^2}$.

This is essentially “Method one” from Riemann's answer, written a bit differently and with slightly better bounds.
For all $n \ge 1$ is
$$
\frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n^2+a_n} \le \frac{1}{n^2}
< \frac{1}{(n-1/2)(n+1/2)} = \frac{1}{n-1/2} - \frac{1}{n+1/2} \\
\implies \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{n-1/2} < \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{n+1/2} \, ,
$$
i.e. the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{n-1/2} \right)_{n}$ is increasing. It follows that
$$
 \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{n-1/2} < \frac{1}{a_m}
$$
for all $m \ge n \ge 2$, or
$$
  \boxed{ a_m < \left( \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{n-1/2} \right)^{-1} \, .}
$$
It suffices to compute $a_2$ to get an upper bound which is strictly less than one. Computing more elements gives better bounds.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n & a_n & \left( \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{n-1/2} \right)^{-1} \\ \hline
1 & \frac 25 & 2 \\
2 & \frac{14}{25} & \frac{42}{47} \approx 0.893617 \\
3 & \frac{399}{625} & \frac{1995}{2327} \approx 0.857327 \\
4 & \frac{267064}{390625} & \frac{38152}{44903} \approx 0.849654\\
\end{array}$$
